# IBM Liberty profile server returning SRTServletRequest instead of spring MultiPartHttpServletRequest

Tags: file-upload, postman, multipartform-data, websphere-liberty, ibm-was-oc

[Postman request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zkQe.jpg)
I am using IBM Websphere 8.5 Liberty server and trying to send a POST request via Postman.
In controller I want to get org.springframework.web.multipart.**MultipartHttpServletRequest**.
But I am getting application server specific **SRTServletRequest31** class inside controller class.

How to resolve it?

In my spring configuration file I have following entry.
<bean id="multipartResolver class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResoler">

Comment: I also tried by unchecking the content-type but no help. I am getting SRTServletRequest which is server is producing. Although the spring dependencies are properly placed and it should give me a spring MultipartHttpServletRequest,

Comment: Can anyone help please? I need to get spring implementation 
 class DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest instead of SRTServletRequest. How can I plugin spring or wrap the default object to spring specific object?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after adding the servlet filter entry for in parent project deployment descriptor. (web.xml).

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter